# Liferay protlet webservice error

Tags: web-services, liferay, portlet

I have a problem with my liferay portlet.

I deployed the portlet fine and am using it in the site.

I have an API/Web Service in my portlet. It was working fine a few days ago, but now I am getting a ClassCastException.

What seems to be the problem?

Here is the stacktrace :

```
AXIS error

Fault - ; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.Handler
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.Handler
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:302)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getHandler(WSDDDeployment.java:394)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:276)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTargetedChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDTargetedChain.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getTransport(WSDDDeployment.java:410)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getTransport(FileProvider.java:257)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getTransport(AxisEngine.java:332)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.generateWSDL(AxisServer.java:441)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler.invoke(QSWSDLHandler.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.processQuery(AxisServlet.java:1226)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at com.liferay.util.axis.AxisServlet.service(AxisServlet.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.AxisServlet.service(AxisServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderServlet.service(PortalClassLoaderServlet.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor353.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:54)
    at $Proxy1003.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:201)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor353.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:54)
    at $Proxy1003.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.Handler
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.Handler
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:302)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getHandler(WSDDDeployment.java:394)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:276)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTargetedChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDTargetedChain.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getTransport(WSDDDeployment.java:410)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getTransport(FileProvider.java:257)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getTransport(AxisEngine.java:332)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.generateWSDL(AxisServer.java:441)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler.invoke(QSWSDLHandler.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.processQuery(AxisServlet.java:1226)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at com.liferay.util.axis.AxisServlet.service(AxisServlet.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.AxisServlet.service(AxisServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderServlet.service(PortalClassLoaderServlet.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor353.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:54)
    at $Proxy1003.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:201)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor353.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:54)
    at $Proxy1003.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:304)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getHandler(WSDDDeployment.java:394)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:276)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTargetedChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDTargetedChain.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getTransport(WSDDDeployment.java:410)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getTransport(FileProvider.java:257)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getTransport(AxisEngine.java:332)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.generateWSDL(AxisServer.java:441)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler.invoke(QSWSDLHandler.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.processQuery(AxisServlet.java:1226)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at com.liferay.util.axis.AxisServlet.service(AxisServlet.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.AxisServlet.service(AxisServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderServlet.service(PortalClassLoaderServlet.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor353.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:54)
    at $Proxy1003.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:201)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor353.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:54)
    at $Proxy1003.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have duplicate axis jars in the portlet and the server lib. Check that first.

liferay-portal-6.1.10-ee-ga1\tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib

vs your portlet libs.

Comment: I did not check that, but deleted all the jar files from my portlet and it worked, so what you are saying could by the problem. Thanks.